# Auto-clear Terminal after every submitted command

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm looking for a way to auto-clear Terminal every time I ran a command. Ideally I would like to only see the results of that last command that I just ran. Is there any way to do this for OSX?

Answer (score -3):

Put the command clear after each command.